# Document by ID not connecting

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was recently working on an assignment for my computer class, but I have a connection error within my code. To my knowledge, the function looks correct.

```
            function idCard(){
            var firstName = document.getElementByID("firstName").value;
            var lastName = document.getElementByID("lastName").value;
            var address = document.getElementByID("address").value;
            
            document.getElementById("postFullName").innerHTML = firstName + "" + lastName;
            document.getElementById("postAddress").innerHTML = address;
            
            var age = document.getElementByID("age").value;
            var phoneNumber = document.getElementByID("phoneNumber").value;
            
            const numberArray = [age,phoneNumber];
            
            for ( var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++){
                if (numberArray[i]<=100){
                document.getElementId("postAge").innerHTML = numberArray[i];
                }
                else{
                document.getElementId("postPhoneNumber").innerHTML = numberArray[i];
                }
            }
            
            }
```

The display works fine, and so far I only get one error from my debugging console,"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function".

Comment: getElementById
That's a typo.

Comment: Closing for typo reason.

Comment: Your question has been answered, you should accept the answer since you already confirmed that community helped you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In JavaScript, Case sensitivity matters,

first 3 lines after the function, it should be getElementById instead of getElementByID, also 6th, 7th line and inside the for loop

innerHTML should work but its usually used to set html,
innerText would be a better option

and good luck with your assignments

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I do have another error message now - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"

Comment: this is probably because the element was not found, check the naming of the id in the html, and if you can try posting the updated js & html